# SQL Server Archiving Options - Separate table vs separate database vs other

Tags: sql-server

My boss wants me to set up an archiving mechanism such that a table does not grow too big and suffer performance issues. We saw a table grow to 11 million row and about 1 gig in size which IMO is not that significant for SQL Server. It has a clustered index on the DateTime column which I don't think would have that much of a performance hit as rows will generally be inserted in chronological order.

What is the best means of archiving (moving and storing elsewhere) that data? If I was to move the data to a separate table within the database would it still slow the database down? Would it be better in terms of performance if I archived the data off into a separate database within the same SQL Server? Or is there another option that trumps the two I'm considering.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find another boss. 11 million is SMALL. Like SMALL. Come back when the database has 10 billion rows. Look into partitioning if you have to.

That said, it depends a lot on what you want and whether the data is invisible for queries or not. Anyhow, sparate data that is not queried wont tax the server -if it is queried then it makes no difference whether it is a separate table or database. Moving the data is best done - in off time (night weekend) by a scheduled job.

Comment: I think the same. I think the performance issue was a result of something else and not the table growth; however I don't have a means of proving it so I'm left with implementing an archiving mechanism.

So in terms of performance it wouldn't matter if the data was moved to a table or database? I might go with the table option then.

Comment: No, space is space - as long as there is no hidden other points table or database make no difference. I would start analysing the queries on the 11 million table row, though, with profler and see whether some stupid index is missing or some stupid SQL in there.